# Using Axios Library In Phaser 3.24.1 Game

Tags: javascript, axios, phaser-framework

I have created a small GET request in an axios call inside my Phaser 3 game, just to test if it works:

```
axios.get('/fetch-new-sudoku')
    .then(function (response) 
    {
        axiosExperiment = response.data.message;
        console.log(response.data, axiosExperiment);
    })
    .catch(function (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () 
    {
        // always executed
    });
```

Inside my Laravel 7 controller I have the following:

```
public function APIFetchNewSudoku()
{
    $data['message'] = "Success";

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

When I open browser inspect I see that the request fires normally with "Success" message shown in the console. When I try to assign the response data message to the var axiosExperiment, it doesn't work at all? I have assigned the axiosExperiment var with a empty string value earlier in my code, like so:

```
var axiosExperiment = "";
```

I would like to be able to assign the response data message to axiosExperiment but dont really know what I am doing wrong? The var remains equal to ""?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have enough information of how you are using axiosExperiment
I'm guessing you are calling axiosExperiment before your promise resolved

try to setText(axiosExperiment ? axiosExperiment : '') on your phaser update()

```
create(){
    var self = this
    this.axiosExperiment = ''
    this.text = this.add.text(0,0, axiosExperiment)

    axios.get('/fetch-new-sudoku')
    .then(function (response) 
    {
        self.axiosExperiment = response.data.message;
        console.log(response.data, axiosExperiment);
    })
}
update(){
     this.text(this.axiosExperiment)
}
```